# Finding the $\gcd$ of polynomials in $\Bbb R[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, gcd-and-lcm

Let $f(x)=6x^3-10x^2-6x+10$ and $g(x)=3x^2-14x+15$ in $\Bbb R[x]$. **I want to find the $\gcd$ of these two polynomials.**

I am not really sure how to do this in general, but my approach was as follows:

Using basic algebra, the zeros of $g$ are $3$ and $5/3$. Thus $g(x)=(x-3)(x-5/3)$. Then I computed $f(3)\neq 0$ and $f(5/3)=0$. So $f$ is of the form $f(x)=(x-5/3)h(x)$ with $h$ being of degree $2$.

Then the $\gcd$ is $(x-5/3)$. Is that true?

Comment: You forget to times 3 on the decomposition of $g(x)$

Comment: It should be 3x-5

Comment: @Zack Ni: IN polynomial ring, the convention is usually to define the gcd as a *monic* polynomial.

Comment: @Bernard I will fix it.

Comment: @Bernard Presumably you mean polynomials over a *field*, since one cannot generally normalize gcds to be monic over more general coefficient rings. In general domains gcds are unique only up to unit factors, i.e. up to associates.

Comment: Yes, as results from the context of the question. Anyway the ring has to be an integral domain, and one can work in its quotient field. Of course, one may also define it as a primitive polynomial in gcd domains and use a system of representative of irreducible elements…

Comment: @Bernard I cannot make any sense of your final sentence. What do you mean to say?

Comment: In order to have well-defined gcd's in polynomial rings over UFDs, you can divide a polynomial by the gcd of its coefficients, so that the polynomial has content $1$. For this its necessary that the gcd in the base ring be uniquely defined, In UFD's this means a system of representative for irreducible elements has to be chosen. For non-UFD gcd domains , I don't know them well enough to say whatever.

Comment: @Bernard If you have a way to choose normal reps from associates in the coefficient ring then you can lift that to polynomials by normalizing the leading coefficient, and this yields gcd normalization for polynomials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your strategy is right but not general. And $g(x)=3(x-3)(x-5/3)=(x-3)(3x-5)$.

In general case, you can do long division and [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_Algorithm):

$ 6x^3-10x^2-6x+10 \equiv 48x-80 \pmod{3x^2-14x+15}$

$gcd(f(x),g(x)) = gcd(g(x),48x-80) = gcd((x-3)(3x-5),16(3x-5)) = 3x-5$ as desired.

EDIT: As Bernard suggests, the great common divisional polynomial should be monic due to convention so $3x-5$ is not the final answer and $gcd(f(x),g(x))$ = $x-5/3$ by dividing the coefficient of first non-zero term.

Comment: The extended version of the Euclidean algorithm also computes the coefficient of a Bézout's relation.

Comment: @Bernard Yes that is it but in polynomial case EEA seems a little useless.

Comment: Why useless? – And why do you mention it if useless? ;o)

Comment: @Bernard I am wrong because I think the polynomial division will have a large complexity on time and the polynomial division and mod can be overkilled by DFFT.

Comment: That's another question. The complexity of the E.E.A. for polynomials of degrees  $\;m\le n\;$ is $\;\frac{13}2mn+O(n)\;$ and $\;\frac52mn+O(n)\;$ for the plain  E.A.